# Add Tuple Object into List Scala

Tags: scala

So I try to add a tuple into list, however the declaration of tuple is same as List in Scala I think.

```
var saveContent = List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)]
val listItem = (1 ,1, 1 , true, 1, 1, 1) //tuple 
saveContent += listItem
saveContent = listItem :: saveContent // doesnt work too
```

Getting type mismake here, I dont want to use Java's Tuple7 in this case.
What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: On a side note, you should use a case class instead of Tuple7 :-) Easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to use the correct syntax to create an empty `List`.

```
var saveContent: List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)] = Nil
```

Then create a tuple with the correct element types.

```
val listItem = (1 ,1, 1 , true, 1L, 1L, 1) //tuple
```

`List` is immutable so it has no `+=` method, but this works.

```
saveContent = listItem :: saveContent
```

Although, of course, you should not be using a `var` if you don't absolutely need it. (And you almost *never* need it.)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
saveContent :+ listItem
```

and convert `var saveContent` to a `val`, you don't need a `var`

Here is the full source code:

```
val saveContent = List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)]()
val listItem = (1 ,1, 1 , true, 1, 1, 1) //tuple 
val result = saveContent :+ listItem
println(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)]()
val listItem = (1 ,1, 1 , true, 1L, 1L, 1) //tuple...note the L at items 5 and 6
// of tuple to represent type `Long`.
val result = saveContent :+ listItem  // works
val result = listItem::saveContent  // this too works
```

***Test in REPL:***

```
scala> val saveContent = List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)]()
saveContent: List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)] = List()

scala> val listItem = (1 ,1, 1 , true, 1L, 1L, 1) //tuple
listItem: (Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int) = (1,1,1,true,1,1,1)

scala> val result = saveContent :+ listItem  // works
result: List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)] = List((1,1,1,true,1,1,1))

scala> val result = listItem::saveContent  // this too works
result: List[(Int, Int, Int, Boolean, Long, Long, Int)] = List((1,1,1,true,1,1,1))
```